# How do I permanently set my bashrc changes?

Tags: bash, path, bashrc

Everytime I log into SSH, I have to manually source the bashrc file to set my path variables the way I want to. How do I have bash do it automatically? Shouldn't it be automatic?

Comment: Should that be `~/.bashrc`?  Probably for PATH I'd put it in `~/.bash_profile`.  Either way, the dot is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

There is the `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash-profile`) file, that runs at every login. You should set environment variables there (with the `export` command). And there is the `~/.bashrc` file, which is run on opening each sell. Commands that are not inherited to all subshells, like alias, can be set here (though for good practise, aliases should be set in `~/.aliases`, which is automatically sourced by `~/.bashrc`).

If it doesn't work for you, you either use a wrong filename (missing "." from beginning?), or you don't use bash as your shell. In the latter case, try `passwd -s /bin/bash` (or `chsh -s /bin/bash`, depending on OS), or call the SSH the following way:

```
ssh username@host bash`
```

Comment: There should be a dot: `~/.bashrc` (you even mention that the OP might be missing a dot!). Also, `~/.aliases` or `~/.bash_aliases` is *not* automatically sourced. There has to be instructions in `~/.bashrc` to *explicitly* do that.

Comment: I think you meant `~/.bash_profile` with an underline, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

You should also know about $BASH_ENV .

What files are read by bash when it starts up depends on if the session is interactive or not.  Occasionally there can be an issue where it's not clear if the session is interactive.  So besides ~/.bashrc you might want to also export and set variable BASH_ENV to point to a file containing the PATH and other settings that you need.  BASH_ENV can be set to point to your .bashrc file (sometimes it's .bash_rc) so long as there are no interactive commands in there (to be safe use a separate file, say ~/.bash_env).  From the bash man pages:

---

When  an  interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and
executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by
using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash to read  and
execute  commands  from  file instead of ~/.bashrc.

When  bash  is  started  non-interactively,  to run a shell script, for example,
it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears
there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.  Bash
behaves as  if  the following command were executed:

```
  if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
```

but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.

---

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i think on a new login shell, bash looks for a single file to run.  It looks for .bash_profile, then .profile, then .bashrc.  If it finds .bash_profile or .profile, it won't further look for .bashrc.

Solution, put in your .profile:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already several (probably correct) answers but I had this exact same problem and this is what worked for me:

add to `~/.bash_profile` the following lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

See [here](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) and [here](http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html) for more info.

(note, in my $HOME directory I already had the following files:
`.bash_aliases`
`.bash_history`
`.bash_logout`
`.bash_profile`
`.bashrc`)

Comment: `bash` won't look for `~/.bashrc` if there's a `~/.bash_profile`.